# Salesforce Integration User License - grant access to Events

Tags: apex, integration

I'm trying to grant access to Event object using the Salesforce Integration User License however, I am having a hard time finding where this could be done.

Per [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) documentation, the event and task objects are collectively referred to as **activities** but I'm unable to find anything in Permission Set or Profile to point to such objects. Ultimately, we need to allow full access (CRUD) to these objects.

How can access to Event can be provisioned on Salesforce profiles OR Permission Sets?

Answer (score 4):

Access to Activities is granted via the 'Access Activities' System Permission.

The steps to enable this access are covered in this help article: [Control Access to Activites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activity_access_user_perm.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you. I will add that "Edit Events" is another setting I found that may be needed to provide if create, edit, and delete events are necessary.